# Mysql Query - Retrieve unused data from another table

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help me. So I have 2 tables metafiles and blogs. I want to get those data in metafiles thats not been used in blogs table which is base on user_id. On this case my user_id = 1

metafiles

| id | name | uid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | c | 1 |
| 4 | d | 2 |
| 5 | e | 1 |
| 6 | f | 1 |

blogs

| pid | metaid | uid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |

And heres the output the I want - these are the metafiles thats not been used

| mid | name | uid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | c | 1 |
| 5 | e | 1 |
| 6 | f | 1 |

The 3,5,6 are under uid 1 but notice its not connected to any data in blogs table.

I tried where not exist but its not working.

Comment: Please can you share the code that you've tried?  We might be able to help you fix it

Comment: @easleyfixed that is a bad suggestion

Comment: @RobEyre heres what i did

SELECT bmf.mid, bmf.uid
                    FROM metafiles bmf
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                        SELECT NULL
                        FROM blogs bb
                        WHERE bb.metaid = bmf.id
                        AND bb.uid = ?
                    )

Comment: and what did that give you, and how did it differ from what you wanted?  please do edit your question and add that.  seems like you may want to check bmf.uid in the main where condition instead or in addition to checking uid in the subquery

Comment: @ysth sorry I just realized that my question is somewhat confusing

Comment: no, it's a pretty standard question; the uid piece and which tables you want to check uid is the only thing that's at all unclear